# Django REST Testing: Attribute Missing

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am trying to test a `User` model and view in a `Python 3.4` environment, but I am having difficulties resolving an issue.

In my app, only staff users should be able to add/delete/modify a user profile. Hence, on `setUp` I create an admin user with the field *is_staff* set. Then, in the test case I force authentication as this admin user, which should allow me to create a new user. This code is shown below:

```
class UserTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.admin = User(username='admin', password='pass', is_staff=True)
        self.admin.save()

    def test_create_user(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new user object without any optional fields.
        """
        url = reverse('user-list')
        data = {'username': 'adam', 'is_staff': False}
        self.client.force_authenticate(user='admin')
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, data)
```

Running this test case results in the follow error trace:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jonathan/GitHub/h2oiq_api/h2oiq_api/test.py", line 19, in test_create_user
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    .
    .
    .
  File "/Users/Jonathan/.virtualenvs/h2oiq-api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 90, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "/Users/Jonathan/.virtualenvs/h2oiq-api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 359, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
    .
    .
    .
  File "/Users/Jonathan/.virtualenvs/h2oiq-api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 304, in check_permissions
    if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
  File "/Users/Jonathan/.virtualenvs/h2oiq-api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 55, in has_permission
    return request.user and request.user.is_staff
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_staff'
```

---

Could someone please elaborate on why this attribute is missing? I have read the Django REST framework documentation thoroughly, especially the [`APIClient`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient), [`Permissions`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), and [`BasicAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication) guides, but I have not been able to find any additional info on this issue. I have tried commenting out the forced authentication, and that did not fix anything.

Any amount of help or insight is appreciated! I am learning Django REST as I go.

Comment: IIRC `force_authenticate()` should be getting a user object, not the string of the username.  So `self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.admin)` in your case.

Comment: @Jkdc Thank you very much. Such a simple fix!

Comment: Glad to help! I'll submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`force_authenticate()` takes a user object for the `user` arguement, not the string of the username.

So in your case you'd use

```
self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.admin)
```